# Grails / Groovy / GGTS: Conflicting module versions on run-app

Tags: eclipse, grails

After upgrading a Grails application from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 I keep getting the following error when attempting to debug a Grails application from GGTS via Debug as... -> Grails Command (run-app):

```
Error starting Grails: nulljava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:62)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:221)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:238)
at groovy.lang.Closure$1.<init>(Closure.java:205)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<clinit>(Closure.java:205)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.<clinit>(GrailsScriptRunner.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.0.5 and you are trying to load version 2.0.7
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerExtensionModuleFromProperties(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:186)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:174)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerClasspathModules(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:156)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:73)
at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
... 14 more
```

I'm running GGTS 3.1.0.RELEASE with the Groovy Compiler 2.0 Feature 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e42RELEASE and Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0.201210061306-RELEASE-e42. The project has configured Groovy Compiler level 2.0. Eclipse Preferences say "You are currently using Groovy Compiler version 2.0.4.xx-20120921-2000-e42RELEASE".

Any hints?

Comment: I think a grails clean might be in order. Refresh dependencies after cleaning and try running the app again.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116091/compatibility-issue-between-the-groovy-all-jars-present-in-eclipse-plugin-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no explanation why it didn't work, but I found a workaround.

I had another run target configured for the same app, but with a `-Dgrails.env=...` setting, which I could launch without problems. I simply copied this config and removed the parameter. That way, I basically recreated the simple launch config which previously kept failing.

Problem gone.

Comment: For what it's worth, I hit this error with a project I recently updated from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1.
Using GGTS 3.2.0 RELEASE with Groovy Compiler 2.0.7.xx-20130304-1200-e42, groovy compiler level 2.0 set for project.  The clean/refresh deps appears to have fixed this issue for me.  Not sure why I started seeing it today, I upgraded the project a few days ago but have successfully run it in run-app as well as war-deployed so... *shrug*

Answer (score 30):

i had this problem on Grails 2.2.0 on Ubuntu machine , i fixed it with the below steps :

1. open eclipse go to "Run as" the "Run Configurations"
2. choose "Environment" tab , then choose "replace native environment with specified environment  "

that solved the problem for me .. hope this help

Comment: Thanks for this tip - it worked in my case.  I think its because I have my groovy project pointed to a newer grails install elsewhere that is using a different groovy version than the one in my STS install.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, I was picking up groovy-all 2.0.7 from GGTS and 2.0.8 from my grails project. To resolve the problem I removed the "Groovy Dependencies" library from the eclipse project.

Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (tab) -> Groovy Dependencies -> Remove

Comment: For me and GGTS 3.4.0 it was: removing "project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (tab) -> Groovy Libraries".  Then clean project, grails clean, grails refresh-dependencies, and all was good.

Comment: I think this is the first thing to try if you're using maven/gradle managed dependencies; it worked perfectly for me, it's a general fix for any groovy project (even if it's not a grails one)

Comment: It worked perfectly for me... Had to live with that error for a while by manually updating pom file. How fool was I!

Answer (score 10):

Manually delete the run-app Run Configuration so it gets recreated. This was reported as a bug on Aug. 1st, 2013. Bug report: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3501

Comment: At first it looked like this worked for me (GGTS 3.4.0 w/ Grails 2.2.4).  But it came back in a subsequent test-app execution.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted .metadata in GGTS workspace and reimport project. It works, I can run-app again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exception, when I was trying to run JUnit tests on my Spring boot project in Eclipse only, mvn executes them fine. I'm not using **Gradle or Groovy**. Indeed checking the test's class path upon debug, showed two versions of groovy.jar. The work version of the groovy.jar was picked from other projects in the Eclipse workspace. I was able to fix it by removing **Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects** in **project properties -> Maven**
[image: Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i solved it by:

1. For your project: Open **Run As**->**Run Configurations**
2. Go to the **Refresh tab**
3. Check the **Refresh resources upon completion**
4. Press **Run**

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing the option to manually load the classpath in Run Configuration. It was using the wrong Grails version (2.5.0 instead of 2.5.1).

Basically the wrong classpath was used.

Maybe this brings someone on the correct path :)

Answer (score 0):

For me a compile from the grails command window did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem  when running it through eclipse and what worked for me is to  make the below changes 
Go to Project properties -> Groovy Compiler ->configure workspace settings . Uncheck the checkbox "Enable checking for mismatch between project and workspace groovy compiler levels"

Answer (score 0):

When I change the grails project's name it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution worked for me when Eclipse stopped being able to run my project with the "groovy-all is loaded in version ... and you are trying to load version" error.

Manually removing a groovy-all line from the .classpath fixed it.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="Libraries/groovy-all-2.1.2.jar"/>
```

I found the solution [in this blog post](http://blog.pdark.de/2014/12/08/groovy-lang-groovyruntimeexception-conflicting-module-versions-module-groovy-all-is-loaded-in-version-2-1-8-and-you-are-trying-to-load-version-2-1-9/).

Comment: I did the same thing via Eclipse. Right click project & choose Build Path --> Configure. Click Libraries tab. Click Groovy Runtime Libraries, then click Remove. Appears to have the same effect as this answer, without hand-editing the `.classpath` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I went to `Project properties -> Groovy Compiler ->configure workspace settings` and I clicked on the "Switch to" button that corresponded to one of the two versions in the error message.
I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a GGTS question, but Google led me here and this seems to be a common issue even after several years so I'm posting this answer here. Hopefully it can help other STS users who also land here.

I had this problem with Spring Tool Suite, using Spring Boot Version 1.3.3.RELEASE and gradle version 2.14. There is some internal dependency on groovy 2.4.6 and groovy-all 2.4.6, but my Eclipse workspace Groovy Libraries are version 2.4.7.  Removing the Groovy Libraries from the Spring/Gradle project properties(s) works for running those projects, but for other Groovy projects in the workspace you are stuck between a rock and a hard place.  They will either run if you click yes when "Errors exist in project. Run anyway?" if you remove the Groovy libs from the properties build path, or they will not have project errors if you put the Groovy libs in the properties build path.

Resolved by adding explicit dependencies in build.gradle on groovy 2.4.7 and groovy-all 2.4.7 for Gradle projects in the workspace

```
compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7')
compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7')
```

and (close Eclipse STS) then removing the 2.4.6 folder(s) from the .gradle cache

```
<path to>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy\2.4.6
<path to>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\2.4.6
```

and (Open STS) then right-click gradle project(s)>gradle>refresh gradle project

Now other Groovy projects in the workspace run without the 2.4.6 vs 2.4.7 conflict.

Answer (score 0):

use mvn denpendency:tree to check your dependencies, maybe there exist version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (using Eclipse 2020-06, 4.16.0) none of the above solutions work any more.

1. Open the Run Configuration of your groovy script
2. Remove all User Entries from the Classpath tab
3. Press "Restore Default Entries"

This should add the default classpath containing your specified Groovy version as User Entry.