# Upgrading Java to 1.8 in GGTS

Tags: java, groovy, grails, ggts

I am currently using GGTS 3.2 and Java 1.7. i MUST upgrade to Java 1.8 as I need to upgrade other software within my code that requires the use of 1.8.
So far I have gotten my code to run in GGTS 3.6.3 but while it runs correctly in the IDE I cannot get it to build a WAR and deploy to my test system.
Also when I try to update to Java 1.8 along with the JRE for 1.8 it will no longer build/run with the following error:

There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1257)

the error is in BuildSettings.groovy:1257 but I can't tell what's actually going wrong. I made no other changes other than to update java.

I am on an air-gapped system so I'm not able to post logs or screenshots.
If anyone has an idea of what may be causing this any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possibly related to [Grails / Groovy / GGTS: Conflicting module versions on run-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079286/grails-groovy-ggts-conflicting-module-versions-on-run-app)

Comment: i tried running through all those links and nothing helped there. still trying to figure out what might be causing it. I tried removing all the dependencies in the buildconfig.groovy since that seems to be where the error is coming from and that didn't help anything.